# Maintain single session for multi application running in different server

Tags: asp.net, iis, session

I have scenario where I need to maintain user session in two applications, both the applications are running in different server and accessing different database. In application1 when user click on button page will navigate to application2 there also user needs to continue with same session.
How can I achieve this, any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to use an out of process session storage instead of the default in-memory so that both servers have access to this centralized session storage location. This could be either SQL Server or Out-Of-Process Windows Service. Then you could perform some [hacking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2007/01/25/sharing-asp-net-session-state-across-applications.aspx) to cheat the ASP.NET framework which forbids you from accessing session from different applications.

Conclusion: IMHO this is not something that you should ever be doing.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a sigle sign on service for authentication:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx